# Cannot reach docker network service but can reach from external IP

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have the following Docker Compose file where I declare 3 services: `db`, `api`, `sdk-py-test`

The service `sdk-py-test` creates a container `craft-sdk-py-test` which sends a bunch of http requests to the GraphQL API container `craft-api` created by the service named `api`.

The requests succeed when `craft-sdk-py-test` sends them on the external URL: `http://172.30.0.3:5433/graphql`

But when I try to send them via the Docker network internal URL: `http://api:5433/graphql` I get immediately an error message:

> gql.transport.exceptions.TransportServerError: 502 Server Error: notresolvable for url: http://api:5433/graphql

How can I use the internal service name `api` to route the requests instead of the IP address?

**Docker Compose File**

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  db:
    container_name: craft-db
    restart: always
    image: craft-db
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

  api:
    container_name: craft-api
    restart: always
    image: craft-api
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 5433:5433

  sdk-py-test:
    container_name: craft-sdk-py-test
    image: craft-sdk-py-test
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.test
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - api
    volumes:
      - ./tests:/tests/tests
      - ./craft:/tests/craft
    command: ["nose2", "-v"]
```

Comment: I thinks that's because of your docker's network not graphQL server. You can check your connection between containers by telnet.

Comment: Thanks @EhsanBarkhordar, I did it by connecting to `craft-sdk-py-test` and I was able to successfully ping `api`. I also successfully telnet `api` on port `5433` and was able to retrieve the API documentation. The network seems somewhat ok in that aspect, I don't understand why other requests do not go through

Comment: Shot in the dark: is `Dockefile.test` trying to `RUN` the end-to-end tests?